# Why does my compound view disappear at usage?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I'm trying to make a custom compound view that handle some data binded to my object called "BaseCF".
The goal is to add a new custom view each time the user press an "add a baseCF" button. The custom view should handle data binding to BaseCF while the main Fragment keeps a Mutablelist of BaseCF.

The adding and deleting of views works just fine but when i try to click into the editText, all the custom views disappear...

Why is that so ? And is the best way to achieve my goal or should i use other method ?

[component tree of my main layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhmae.png)

BasesCFLayout into my main layout :

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bouton_ajouter_sequence_SR2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/btn_add_sq2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv_seq" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutBasesCF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bouton_ajouter_sequence_SR2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnAddBaseCf"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAddBaseCf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="@string/btn_add_bases_cf"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_save"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnDeleteBasesCf"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bouton_ajouter_sequence_SR2" />
```

CustomView :

```
class FormForBaseView(context: Context, baseCF: BaseCF) : ConstraintLayout(context) {


    init {

        inflate(context, R.layout.item_form_base_cf, this )

        val titleBaseCFTextView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.title_base_CF)
        val inputNbSR4orGR: TextInputEditText = findViewById(R.id.inputNbSR4GR)
        val inputNbEB: TextInputEditText = findViewById(R.id.inputNbEB)
        val inputNbGR: TextInputEditText = findViewById(R.id.inputNbGR)
        val inputNbValPlafondCF: TextInputEditText = findViewById(R.id.inputValeurPlafondCF)

        titleBaseCFTextView.text = context.getString(R.string.title_base_cf, baseCF.numBase)

        // Si la base existe déjà, préremplir les valeurs
        baseCF.nbsr4gr?.let { inputNbSR4orGR.setText(it.toString()) }
        baseCF.nbeb?.let { inputNbEB.setText(it.toString()) }
        baseCF.nbgroupes?.let { inputNbGR.setText(it.toString()) }
        baseCF.plafondCF?.let { inputNbValPlafondCF.setText(it.toString()) }


        inputNbSR4orGR.doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ ->
            if (!text.isNullOrBlank())
                baseCF.nbsr4gr = Integer.parseInt(text.toString() )
            else
                baseCF.nbsr4gr = null
        }

        inputNbEB.doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ ->
            if (!text.isNullOrBlank())
                baseCF.nbeb = Integer.parseInt(text.toString())
            else
                baseCF.nbeb = null
        }

        inputNbGR.doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ ->
            if (!text.isNullOrBlank())
                baseCF.nbgroupes = Integer.parseInt(text.toString())
            else
                baseCF.nbgroupes = null
        }

        inputNbValPlafondCF.doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ ->
            if (!text.isNullOrBlank())
                baseCF.plafondCF = Integer.parseInt(text.toString())
            else
                baseCF.plafondCF = null
        }


    }

}
```

And into my main fragment :

```
btnAddBaseCf.setOnClickListener{
            nbBases++
            basesCF.add(BaseCF(numBase = nbBases))
            layoutBasesCF.addView( FormForBaseView(requireContext(), basesCF[nbBases-1]))
        }

        btnDeleteBasesCf.setOnClickListener {
            nbBases = 0
            basesCF.clear()
            layoutBasesCF.removeAllViews()
        }
```